# Virtual Entities - Cosmos DB connector issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-cosmosdb, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I was trying to set up simple Cosmos DB virtual entities example that worked before on Dynamics 365 Online, but I got a strange error "**The specified domain does not exist or cannot be contacted**" when I tried to load the view. Tried to run it in classic UI and there is also the same issue.

[image]

That error is not helping at all so I checked the Network output on the browser and I found the new error "**Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': The specified module could not be found.**" that seems like a common error nowadays while using wrong NuGet packages in custom development.

I'm trying to solve this for 2 days now, but with no luck. Does anyone have an idea how can we fix it?

Comment: are you able to reach API for cosmos DB outside CRM i.e just by giving URL in Browser.

Comment: I can reach it, but I get:  `{ "code": "Unauthorized", "message": "Required Header authorization is missing. Ensure a valid Authorization token is passed.\r\nActivityId: 605417fb-665c-4870-9e65-ffc03ce3d0f3, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.2.0.0" }`

Comment: As you can see from Error, It gives an unauthorized access. I would suggest you try to reach API via browser first, If that works then it will mostly work in CRM.

If I may suggest if you wish to do POC for Virtual Entity, try visiting odata website https://www.odata.org/ where you can find sample Odata api. Below is the one I used for my Virtual entity POC.

https://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Advertisements

Below is Youtube video to try POC.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3WNc7N9VkI

Comment: OData and custom connector are working just fine. I have problems only with Cosmos DB one.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. The cosmos API is reachable, no problem there. It just doesn't work from CRM